# How to create php class for navigation action

Tags: php

Can someone tell me how to create php class to for navigation action, I would like to write url like this on browser

suppose if I want home page then

http://myserver.mydomain.com/index/home then 
action will be home function index.php.

I know i can achieve this using `$_POST` and `$_GET`, but I want to try something like how codeigniter works like that so far I tried like this

```
<?php

 class Index {

 function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
 }

function home(){
      include('test/header.php');
      include('test/home.php');
      include('test/footer.php');
}

function about(){
      include('test/header.php');
      include('test/about.php');
      include('test/footer.php');
}

}


?>
```

Comment: Why not rewrite the URL with .htaccess, and use `_GET` to load the specific controllers/models/view for a specific "page". It would be much better as you wouldn't have to add another function for each page - but only the logic (model/controller/view - should you choose the MVC approach)

Comment: CodeIgniter uses `$_GET` etc., too: http://www.8tiny.com/source/codeigniter/nav.html?system/libraries/Router.php.source.html

Comment: You cant call parent::__construct() if you dont have a parent class! What you are looking for is a router script, such as https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter

Comment: I am sorry I am not interested to use codeigniter, I want to achieve this without codeigniter

Comment: I did not suggest to **use** codeigniter, I commented the link to show you how codeigniter does it, that's what you are asking for: *but I want to try something like how codeigniter works like*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have the following rewrite rule;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite a request like; `http://example.php/index.php?module=about` to `http://example.php/about`

Now, let's see how the Router is done;

- It's very basic
- Can be improved a lot

```
<?php

class Router {
    private $strModule;     //Holds the module to load (the page)

    public function __construct(){}

    public function setModule($strModuleName) {
        $this->strModule = $strModuleName;
    }

    public function loadModule() {
        if( file_exists('modules/'. $this->strModule .'.php') ) {
            include 'modules/'. $this->strModule .'.php';
        } else {
            'modules/404.php';
        }
    }

}
```

Now, let's use the router in `index.php`

```
$objRouter = new Router();
$objRouter->setModule($_GET['module']);
$objRouter->loadModule();
```

And our tree will be like;

```
 - index.php
 - modules/
    - about.php
    - 404.php
```

Of course, this is just a quick job, and it ***can*** be improved a lot.

I hope that helps.

**Note:**
 *The pretty urls (.htaccess rewrite rules) are just for eye-candy. You can achieve this by not using rewrite rules, even with the same code supplied above*