# How to redirect my pages to index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to know why when I go on my site http://nextgenfocus.com/, index.php does not in the URL and the content is not fully displayed. I tried with a .htaccess file, but nothing helped.

My index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "index.php") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Home</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "downloads") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Downloads</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "help") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Help</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("top_bar.php");?>
        <?php include("container.php");?>
        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How I can do, please?

Comment: Do you want to load http://nextgenfocus.com/index.php by typing http://nextgenfocus.com/ automatically?

Comment: Are you sure that the "container.php" file is where it should be (the same directory level) and it's not empty?

Comment: Hi, yes, I want the index.php directly when I type in the URL nextgenfocus.com. The container is linked to index.php, so no, it's not empty. if you go to nextgenfocus.com/index.php, the content is here, but if you go to nextgenfocus.com, the container is not here because the index.php is not redirected.

Comment: do you have index.html file in same directory? if there, rename that for now

Comment: This is a bad approach to what you're doing. Take a look at using a router: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015222/how-to-create-php-class-for-navigation-action/25015462#25015462

Comment: What is there in your container.php ?

Comment: Hi  We7dy, have you tried renaming index.html file?

Comment: In the container.php: http://prntscr.com/47r08q

Comment: Hi, I have no index.html file in the root of my site, I just have the index.php.

Comment: how this opens http://nextgenfocus.com/index.html?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're trying to match on request uri, that is what you read on your browser address box. You shold match on `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` index

you could use this code for matching your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "index.php") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Home</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "downloads") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Downloads</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "help") !== false) { ?>
        <title>Test - Help</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("top_bar.php");?>
        <?php include("container.php");?>
        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can avoid to redirect browser by matching another variable instead. If you go on http://nextgenfocus.com/, your "REQUEST_URI" index would be just "/", but "SCRIPT_FILENAME" will be something like "/var/www/your/path/index.php" which is the script file actually loaded

Comment: What I need to do for fix the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try to configure your httpd config and add DirectoryIndex to default execute index.php if found in that path.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, if you really want to redirect via Apache you should paste this code in your .htaccess

`RewriteEngine  on
Redirect /  /index.php`

**BE SURE** that your apache has mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: I replaced REQUEST_URI by SCRIPT_FILENAME. But why? Why it works with this?

Comment: When I use the .htaccess method, I get this error: http://prntscr.com/47r2l0 mod_rewite is enabled.

Comment: Because visiting `site.com/` your're not actually querying a file named `index.php`, it's apache that handles the request in this way. Your REQUEST_URI represents exactly what browser is asking for, SCRIPT_FILENAME instead what apache used to satisfy

Comment: If I want use the .htaccess method, how I can do, please?

Comment: You have probably some other configuration in conflict with this, just use the working solution ;)

Comment: It works perfectly! I searched all the night for this problem and you have fixed the problem very quickly. Thank you really! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your container.php file

```
 <?php if((strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "index.php") !== false) && (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/") !== false)){ ?>
     <div id="container">
         <!-- Your code here -->
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```